# Script to trigger function on cell value being true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script function that emails the active sheet as an excel file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG9vz.png)

Is there a script that will run the function if the value in cell range U2:U90 is 'Yes'?

Comment: Which value in `U2:U90` there is 89 values in that range.

Comment: Hi, all cells in that range normally stay empty, but what I want is that if any data gets imputed into any one of those cells (it will only happen once, before sheet gets refreshed) then it sets of the script. Basically the column is a response to a question on the form which asks if the timesheet is complete. If it's not then the user just ignore that question and continues to submit data. When the user has finished, they will click yes, this is when the data in the column (any of the 90 cells) will change, triggering the script to run

Comment: Just to be clear about this, when the user clicks on "yes", is this a button you made in your sheet? Does the script run because of the "yes", or because the "yes" checks the column U and finds a change in the data?

Comment: Yes, it's a multiple choice option in the form but instead of having yes or no,  i've just left it as yes. If the user has mor data to input, they just submit and go around again until the select yes. Also as there will be many submits before yes is selected, it may be anywhere in column U from row 2 to 90

Comment: Welcome. The information that you have been disclosing in these comments should be, and should have been, in your question - for everyone to read. Please re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit your question to explain your scenario more fully. You might also include any research or code that you have already developed - we don't want to double up on research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot write the code for you but we can give you some tips. You have to create a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for your Form, and in your script add a condition to the "Yes" [item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response.html), like:

```
  var response = event.response;
  if (response.getItemResponses()[i].getResponse()) == "Yes"){
     //do stuff
  }
```

Then, you have to get the data from U2:U90. You can do it with the method [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). This returns you an array with the values of the cells. Iterate through them and compare each one with the value that will trigger the function.

```
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
     if (values[i] != "") { //checks if value is different from empty
       runFunction();
       break;
     }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much , I will try this out later.